# Ember component event not tirggered

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a sidenav component with a toggle button to open or close it.

**/templates/components/side-nav.hbs**

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <span role="button" class="toggle-menu svg-icons" {{ action 'toggle' on='click' }}></span>
</div>
```

**components/side-nav.js**

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        toggle: function(){
            console.log('click');
        }
    }
});
```

**/templates/application.hbs**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    {{side-nav}}
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

The event is not fired no matter what. I know this is basic stuff, but I've spent hours not being able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `on=click`. Try just:

```
<span role="button" class="toggle-menu svg-icons" {{action 'toggle'}}></span>
```